# Understanding Promise and Await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am just trying to understand how *Promises* and *Async-Await* work. 
I want this to resolve by logging `1, 2, 3` in that order. *Currently* it logs `1, 3, 2`.

I know the *Promise* doesn't really make sense here but in my program it has other uses so that needs to stay. The route from `Caller` function to `Test` also needs to stay (If need be you can change these but just know that they are there for a reason)

My question is how do I wait for the `Caller` function to resolve?

### Here is my code:

```js
function Test() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('2');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  })
}

function Caller() {
  Test();
}

console.log('1');
Caller();
console.log('3');
```

I have tried what I understand, which is to make the Caller() function await the Test Promise, but that of course makes the Caller() function async and therefore we still get 1, 3, 2

```
async function Caller() {
    await Test();
}
```

Is there maybe some way to use await without making the function async?

Comment: you should await the caller in your example, so move everything in to an iife. On the other hand, you could also do caller().then( () => console.log(3) ). await only works in async functions

Comment: Once you step on asychronous timeline you can never return back to sycnhronous timeline again. So `console.log(3)` comes before your async operation. The `await` methodology mentioned under many of the  answers is an illusion to make you feel confortable. In reality it pushes the trailing code into the async timeline without showing you explicitly. IMHO you should follow promise way as a realistic person in order not to mix up sychronous code with the async ones. But this is only my feeling.

Comment: @Icepickle Thank you for your reply and idea :)

Comment: @Redu Thank you for your reply as well. I agree with the problem of once you async you can't ever go back. But what do you mean with you IMHO line? I would like a solution to this idea.

Comment: I mean, I prefer doing it like `Caller().then(_ => console.log(3))` which explicitly shows that you are in an async timeline established by `Caller` function.

Comment: Ah now I understand Icepickle's answer also. You guys should post .then as an official answer. It is definitely a good solution

Answer (score 5):

- You can only `await` a function that returns a promise (well, not quite true, if it doesn't return a promise it creates a promise that resolves instantly)
- You can only `await` when you are inside an asynchronous function

```js
function test() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('2');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  })
}

async function caller() {
  console.log('1');
  await test();
  console.log('3 (this is blocked awaiting the promise');
}

caller()
console.log("This is not blocked because caller is async");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very straightforward, simple way of doing what you ask.

> The `await` keyword can only be used inside functions
>   defined with `async`.

```js
function test(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function caller() {
  console.log(1, ' - caller() started');
   
  await test(2000).then(() => {
      console.log(2, ' - test() resolved')
  });
  
  console.log(3, ' - delayed until "test()" has resolved');
  
  return 4;
}

// wait for "caller()" to resolve
caller().then((result) => {
    console.log(result, " - caller() finished")
});

console.log(5);
```

Here's a good article by Google which expands on the subject:
[Async functions - making promises friendly](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions).

Cite [source](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9#59b2).

Answer (score 0):

here is how you could use functions like this:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(() => r(), ms);
  });
}

(async () => {
  console.log(1);
  await sleep(1000); // 1s
  console.log(2);
  await sleep(2000) // 2s
  console.log(3)
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

The previous answers are all correct but I just feel like this answer makes more sense. It is more accurate to the original question's code:

```js
function Test() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('2');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  })
}

function Caller() {
  return Test();
}

(async() => {
  console.log('1');
  await Caller();
  console.log('3');
})();
```